# Inclusion and exclusion with sets of functions

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

"Denote by S the set of integers {18,19,...,22}. Count the number of BIJECTIVE functions φ:S→S such that φ(x)≠x for all x∈S."

Above is the question.  I understand the total bijective functions possible are 5! but I don't know how to exclude the last bit of the question "such that φ(x)≠x for all x∈S".  Is there something that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, what if you count them all and take out the ones that fix at least one number?

Comment: I counted $48$ but couldn't find a neat way to represent it with $nPr$ or $nCr$.

Comment: The term to search for is "derangements".